# I can't make a project in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

On the documentation and tutorials for making a project in VScode I see File > New > Project. But I do not have this option on Mac or Linux?!? Maybe it is only available on Windows?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/get-started/tutorial-console-cpp?view=msvc-170&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2022
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you are looking at is for completely different IDE software. This documentation is for "Visual Studio" not "Visual Studio Code"

For VS Code you will need a [plugin](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)